# Place ')' on new line when method call arguments are long is not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea, layout, coding-style

In Intellij I am configuring `Wrapping and braces`. When calling a method that gets too long (exceeds the vertical line) I want to set the method parameter onto the next line and the closing parenthesis too. Even though the option is available it looks like it is not working.

[image]

Is there a rule to help me doing this?

Comment: Does it work in editor (not in preview)?

Comment: in none of those

Comment: Could you please share screenshot from "Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style"?